# Clustering column "status" cannot be restricted (preceding column "datetime" is restricted by a non-EQ relation

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax

I have the datetime column only for the sorting purpose and rest of clustering keys are for filtering. But I can't filter by other columns without giving equivalent value to datetime. If I use Apache solr, can I solve my problem?

My table:

```
create table search_by_company_id_status
(
agency_id   text,
datetime    timestamp,
createid    text,
status  text,
primary key ((agency_id),datetime,status,createid)) with clustering order by (datetime desc);
```

Query I am trying:

```
select * from search_by_agency_id_status  where agency_id='125' and datetime>'2018-02-02 12:00:00.000' and recordstatus='7' and createid='id234';
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the query you have provided, you are filtering with "equal to" predicates on the rest of the clustering columns namely "status" and "createdid".

You can redesign the table as follows which guarantees the sorted order on datetime (since each of the prior values are filtered for a single value).

```
create table search_by_company_id_status
(
agency_id   text,
datetime    timestamp,
createid    text,
status  text,
primary key ((agency_id),status,createid,datetime)) with clustering order by (datetime desc);
```

This query should work fine

```
select * from search_by_agency_id_status  where agency_id='125' and status='7' and createid='id234' and datetime>'2018-02-02 12:00:00.000';
```

Comment: I didn't follow that because I don't always filter by status and createid, those two column are just optional guess i am gonna have to create 2 more tables to satisfy the filtering. Thanks for answering.